# TPageControl component in Delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

Is there an option to use same components (check boxes, `TEdit`s, etc.) on different tabs on `TPageControl` component?

Comment: What you mean by use the same component?

Comment: use `TTabControl`. For placing not-shared controls use `TNotebook` or another `TPageControl` with ever page's `xxx.TabVisible = false`. Switch them manually from `TTabControl.OnChange`

Comment: or move "shared" components outside the page control, for example above it or left from it.

Comment: @Arioch'The The problem is that I figured out too late that they will share some fields. I guess I'm gonna copy/paste them

Comment: @Sami like the tedit, because later I am connecting it to same table in SQL base and I use that data to filter the results in DataGrid

Comment: Why doesn't anyone mention frames? That is what I would use.

Comment: @Rudy almost at the same time I was thinking the same thought.  Mention of data linked controls suggests a whole further level of complexity but hard to say how that fits with the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no because each page is a separate object. If you want to use the same controls on every page, use TTabControl instead.

If you need to use TPageControl, there are ways to dynamically move controls between pages but usually it is simpler to just copy and paste.